# Capturar página com PHP Curl

Tags: php, jquery, libcurl, file-get-contents

Pessoal preciso capturar o código fonte de uma página com cURL, porém o jQuery desta página que gera o conteúdo e o cURL não retorna estes dados gerados com jQuery, tem alguma forma de capturar o código fonte da página após ela ser renderizada já com o jQuery em funcionamento? Estou usando PHP.

Comment: Não tem como, o que pode fazer e tentar pegar os dados do jQuery e trazer para o PHP. Uma outra solução, caso o jQuery carregue uma página externa é justamente fazer o cURL nesta página, carregando os cookies/headers nativos. A solução que deseja precisará usar um Webdriver, um navegador nativo que abrirá a página e irá coletar os dados, mas será imensamente mais pesado e complicado do que o cURL.

Comment: Vou te explicar @Inkeliz: tenho um plugin de calendário em jquery (zabuto_calendar) que gera um calendário e preciso pegar esta página e transformar em pdf. Estou usando o mpdf, ja tentei com dompdf também, porém em ambos carrega só o html e css mas o jquery não carrega. Não estou achando uma solução.

Comment: Nunca ouvir falar neste `zabuto_calendar`, mas vendo a documentação ele possui isso: `$("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar( { ajax: { url: "{YOUR_URL}" } } ` ou `$("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar( { data: [] } );`. Logo, pegue os dados (se for o primeiro caso, entre no url do ajax para carregar). Dai você terá os dados. Crie uma tabela HTML/CSS (sem javascript), processado pelo PHP, e substitua no HTML principal do cURL, por exemplo, fazendo um `replace` no `<div id="my-calendar"></div>`. Dessa forma terá os dados substituídos.

Comment: você precisa da página inteira ou somente dos dados carregados via ajax pela página que deseja "grabear"? Se for somente para obter os dados gerados pelo ajax (enviado por jquery), basta ler diretamente a url que requisita via ajax.